# Giving each element a different text (loop, array)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a pixabay array. I did manage to get the data from my array.

[image]
As you can see I've got 3 cards with 3 different pictures from my pixabay array.

But what I hope to get is that those 3 cards each have different titles and text.

This is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

This is my code:

```
`componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://pixabay.com/api/?key=11095386-871fd43c33a92700d9bffb82d&q=travel&image_type=photo&pretty=true")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            apiImg: result.hits
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }` --> this is where I fetch my api
```

This is my card:

```
`{
            apiImages.slice(0,9).map(img => (
            <Card className="api" shadow={5} style={{ minWidth: '450', margin: 'auto' }}>
            <a href="/alleblogs">
            <CardTitle style={{ 
                color: '#fff', 
                height: '176px', 
                backgroundImage: url(${img.largeImageURL}), 
                backgroundPosition: 'center', 
                backgroundSize: 'cover'
            }}>Golden Bridge</CardTitle>
            <CardText>
                Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis distinctio esse qui eos, ad provident,
            </CardText>
            <CardActions border>
                <Button style={{ color: '#8dd5e8' }}>Likes:</Button>
                <Button style={{ color: '#8dd5e8' }}>Share</Button>
            </CardActions>
            </a>
            </Card>
            ))
            }`
```

As you can see I'm using a loop with only one card. But what I want is to have 3 cards with each a different text and title.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: You have to determine how your titles and texts are corresponding to your images.

Comment: I guess with the help of that card? In my card I hava my card title, text and image

Comment: Does `apiImages` images return only images?  You need to pre-process those images into an array of objects that correlate img sources to card title and description text, then map that in the render function.  Also, what is the `apiImages.slice` for?

Comment: Yeah It's very complicated, because when I type: `apiImages.slice(0,20)` my website will show 20 cards.. largeImageURL is specifically for the image return. I don't know if I can pre-process that array because it's an public api I can't change.

Comment: Why is your entire code in a string ?

Comment: What I meant by preprocess was to construct the array you actually want to render in the API success handler.  i.e. filter/slice down the image results  array to what you want and then tack on the title and description text objects.  What you want to save into state is something like `[{title: '...', description: '...', image: imgSrcA}, {title: '...', description: '...', image: imgSrcB}, ... {title: '...', description: '...', image: imgSrcN}]`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know.. This is what someone said I should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of "preprocessing" I was trying to explain/suggest.

```
const cardData = [
  {
    title: 'Golden Bridge',
    description: 'Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis distinctio esse qui eos, ad provident,'
  },
  {
    title: 'card title 2',
    description: 'description 2'
  },
  {
    title: 'card title 3',
    description: 'description 3'
  },
];

componentDidMount() {
  fetch("https://pixabay.com/api/?key=11095386-871fd43c33a92700d9bffb82d&q=travel&image_type=photo&pretty=true")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(results => {
    // do preprocessing here
    const cards = results.hits.reduce((cards, hit, index) => {
      cards.push({
        ...cardData[index % cardData.length], // no index out of bounds
        image: hit.largeImageURL
      });
      return cards;
    }, []);
    this.setState({
      cards
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    this.setState({
      isLoaded: true,
      error
    });
  });
}

const renderCard = ({image, title, description}) => (
  <Card className="api" shadow={5} style={{ minWidth: '450', margin: 'auto' }}>
    <a href="/alleblogs">
      <CardTitle
        style={{
          color: '#fff', 
          height: '176px', 
          backgroundImage: url(${image}), 
          backgroundPosition: 'center', 
          backgroundSize: 'cover'
        }}
      >
        {title}
      </CardTitle>
      <CardText>{description}</CardText>
      <CardActions border>
        <Button style={{ color: '#8dd5e8' }}>Likes:</Button>
        <Button style={{ color: '#8dd5e8' }}>Share</Button>
      </CardActions>
    </a>
  </Card>
);

render() {
  const { cards } = this.state;
  return (
    /* ... other code stuffs */
    {
      cards && cards.map(this.renderCard);
    }
    /* ... more code stuffs */
  );
}
```

Comment: One question though, what do you mean with: `render() {
        const { cards } = this.state;
        return (
          ...
          {
            cards && cards.map(this.renderCard);
          }
          ...
        );
      }`

Comment: Used ellipses "..." in the render function to represent other code around how you'd want to render the cards.  They are *not* the spread operator, sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Thanks again for helping me ;) .......http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=4fva7q&s=9#.XDMVzVxKjIU And what do you mean with ` { card && cards.map  }` because visual studio code underlined that code red also

Comment: It's a javascript/react convention.  If `cards` is defined and truthy, javascript will continue evaluating the rest of the expression, which is the mapping in this case.  If `cards` is undefined or otherwise falsey, react will render null for that section.  You don't want to call functions on undefined variables.

Comment: I got this as well: 'renderCard' is declared but its value is never read.ts

Comment: Visual studio code is saying that this code is fault: `render() { const { cards } = this.state; return ( ... { cards && cards.map(this.renderCard); } ... ); }`

Comment: I have updated my answer to comment out the ellipses, they aren't renderable alone. Can you posted here the error, and the code you have that goes with it, or copy it to a https://codesandbox.io code sandbox?

Comment: Thanks for learning me that new tool! :D pretty helpful.. here is the link ---> https://codesandbox.io/s/6xn0lw3q3z  ----> http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=13yfh34&s=9#.XDOCiVxKjIW

Comment: Try https://codesandbox.io/s/214j24501p.  I had to add all your imports and comment out some code that was breaking, but it renders cards with images and text.

Answer (score 0):

this cant be the best one . but can solve your problem.

just change yours as below ..

```
<CardTitle style={[{ 
                color: '#fff', 
                height: '176px', 
                backgroundImage: url(${img.largeImageURL}), 
                backgroundPosition: 'center', 
                backgroundSize: 'cover'
            }, {...stylesFromParent } ]}>Golden Bridge</CardTitle>
```

// i just added local styles and styles which has been send to this component as props from parent.

// i think managing styles in parent component and do some logic which styles to set to which card can solve this .

//example like saving styles in consts

```
const greenCardStyle = {
    color: orange,
    fontWeight: 600
}
```

// and then decide which style to put on which card ...   managed from parent componet.

hope this will help .

stay blessed